# Dropbox PHP API error

Tags: php, api, dropbox

I've been developing a music website that plays `.mp3` files from a Public dropbox folder, and I think I've found a solution on how to get file names from a directory in Dropbox.The code I've found is:

```
$consumerKey = 'key';
$consumerSecret = 'key';

require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";

session_start();
$oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PHP($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$dropbox = new Dropbox_API($oauth);

$info = $dropbox->getMetaData('Public', true);
print_r($info['contents']);
```

The `autoload.php` is in the right directory, all necessary files are present.But the error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Dropbox_OAuth_PHP' not found in C:\wamp\www\api\index.php on line 10
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it successfully loading the `autoload.php`?

Comment: Well it's showing on directory index... so I guess.And it would probably show some other error too.

Comment: The current documentation for the SDK doesn't reflect this code at all: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php - perhaps what ever code you copied is old? The current SDK isn't used this way at all.

Comment: That well might be it.I'll check on that.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the `require_once` part, if the file was missing it would crash and the script execution would stop and you wouldn't be seeing the fatal error on line `$oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PHP($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);`.

Comment: Okay there's even more problems, i took the code from dropbox dev site and now It's saying: `The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers`

Comment: try `echo PHP_INT_MAX`. what's the output?

Comment: Commented out the block of code that threw this exception, now everything works (for now)